# Sphinx n-gram & charset_table

Tags: sphinx

I'm modifying the charset mapping for a sphinx cluster and I've run into a bit of an oddity, one which the documentation does not cover. The previous author of the `charset_table` and `ngram_chars` definitions has put the CJK unicode ranges in **both** charset mapping and ngrams.

Is this necessary?

If not, what is the purpose of this duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question after doing some extensive testing. As it turns out, `charset_table` and `ngram_chars` complement each other rather than one being a subset of the other.

### Testing run

**Docset**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <sphinx:docset>
 <sphinx:schema>
    <sphinx:field name="foo"/>
     </sphinx:schema>
     <sphinx:document id="123">
    <foo><![CDATA[ぇえぉおかがきぎく]]></foo>
</sphinx:document>
</sphinx:docset>
```

**Just `charset_table`**

```
using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
index 'i_blah': query 'ぇ ': returned 0 matches of 0 total in 0.000 sec

using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
index 'i_blah': query 'ぇえぉおかがきぎく ': returned 1 matches of 1 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=123, weight=1500

words:
1. 'ぇえぉおかがきぎく': 1 documents, 1 hits
```

**Just `ngram_chars`**

```
using config file 'sphinx.conf'...
index 'i_blah': query 'ぇえぉおかがきぎく ': returned 1 matches of 1 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:
1. document=123, weight=9500

words:
1. 'ぇ': 1 documents, 1 hits
2. 'え': 1 documents, 1 hits
3. 'ぉ': 1 documents, 1 hits
4. 'お': 1 documents, 1 hits
5. 'か': 1 documents, 1 hits
6. 'が': 1 documents, 1 hits
7. 'き': 1 documents, 1 hits
8. 'ぎ': 1 documents, 1 hits
9. 'く': 1 documents, 1 hits
```

So, the presence of a character in `charset_table` does not in any way affect the indexing if the character is present in `ngram_chars`. They do not depend on one another.

Answer (score 0):

I admit never used ngram_chars, but I think chars listed in `ngram_chars` do also need to be in `charset_table`

'charset_table', defines all chars that get indexed, then 'ngram_chars' defines ones that get segmented.

if only in 'charset_table' then will be indexed as normal words

if only in 'ngram_chars' then have no effect.

Comment: I spent 30 minutes building a test scenario for it. Turns out they're independent - check my answer.